# Querying SuDocuments in MongoDB using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to add a value in sub-document in mongoDB using node js.
The schema is :

```
    var commentSchema = new Schema({
    author:String,
    data:String,
    postedAt:Date
});

var likeSchema = new Schema({
    likedBy:{
        type:Array,
        default:[""]
    },
    numOfLikes:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    }
});

var picSchema = new Schema({
    url:String,
    likes:[likeSchema],
    comments:[commentSchema]
});

var statusSchema = new Schema({
    data:String,
    likes:[likeSchema], 
    comments:[commentSchema]
});

var profileSchema = new Schema({
    username:String,
    password:String,
    DOB :Date,
    sex: String,
    Address:String,
    pic:[picSchema],
    Status:[statusSchema]
});
```

I want one user to add comment to other user's pic. 
The method that I am using right now is :

```
profile.update({"username":recepient,"pic._id":id},{$set:{"pic.comments":{"author":user,"data":comment,"postedAt":new Date()}}}},function(err,data){
                    if (err){
                        throw err;
                    }else{
                        console.log(data);
                        res.status(200).json({status:"Added successfully"});
                    }
```

Here I am getting the error as : cannot use part pic of pic.comments to traverse.

When I am using the update statement as :

```
profile.update({"username":recepient,"pic._id":id},{$set:{"comments":{"author":user,"data":comment,"postedAt":new Date()}}},function(err,data){
                    if (err){
                        throw err;
                    }else{
                        console.log(data);
                        res.status(200).json({status:"Added successfully"});
                    }
```

I am not getting any error, but the value is not getting added.

Is there some mistake with the update statement or the schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Profile*** has ***[Pic]***, ***Pic*** has ***[Comments]***, if you want to update ***Pic*** by `"pic._id":id` then you should query for Pic model, not profile. SubDocuments a little bit look like sql tables

```
pic.update({ // update Pic model, not Profile
    "pic._id": id // removed "username":recepient as you already have picId
  }, {
    $set: {
      "comments": {
        "author": user,
        "data":comment,
        "postedAt":new Date()
      }
    }
  }, function(err,data){
       if (err){
         throw err;
       console.log(data);
       res.status(200).json({status:"Added successfully"});
  }
```

Comment: Here the database is defined in a separate file. From there I am exporting the profileSchema module. This export is now being used at other places as well, like for passport authentication. So when I write two export statements in the database file, I am getting an error in the passport authenticate function. Because, there we 'require' the file, from where the exported 'module' gets called.
Any idea for this?